# JQuery drag and drop position on multiple drop to one droppable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a very simple drag and drop quiz, where the user has a list of 8 actions that they must drag into the correct drop area (there are 3 drop areas). So I might have 2 or 3 items being dropped onto one droppable div.

This works fine except the actions are dragged on top of the previous dropped action, rather than stacking beneath.

I cant seem to find a definitive list of options to use with ui.draggable.position. This is the code I'm currently using to place the drop:

```
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
```

But as I said above, they are just placed on top of the previous drop.

Below is the style that is being generated by 2 dragged items onto 1 draggable area. It is adding a -50px top margin to the second element, which is why its behind. how can i stop this?:

1st draggable div:

```
<div id="section1" class="ui-draggable correct ui-draggable-disabled ui-state-disabled" style="position: relative; z-index: 8; left: 410px; top: 0px;" aria-disabled="true">Use one measure of soap</div>
```

2nd draggable div:

```
<div id="section1" class="ui-draggable correct ui-draggable-disabled ui-state-disabled" style="position: relative; z-index: 9; left: 410px; top: -50px;" aria-disabled="true">Rinse thoroughly (fingers/thumbs/wrists)</div>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Heres the demo app: [link to demo app](http://enetsystems.co.uk/drag/)

Can anyone shed any light how to get these to stack properly?

Much appreciated
Alan

Comment: How is the negative margin being added? Am i going mad?

Answer (score 1):

Without reconsider the drag/drop handling clone instead of move, you can do like this.

First not use multiple time the same id for more element, use a class instead or a data attribute; the following example use an attr called `section`.

In the drop function check if there are other elements already dropped in the same section; when you drop an item you add a class `correct`, so you can get the number and increment the position of the top.

```
            var addTop=$( "div .correct[section='"+slotNumber+"']").length*70;

            ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
            ui.draggable.draggable('disable');

            ui.draggable.position({
                of: $(this),
                my: 'left top+'+addTop,
                at: 'left top'
            });
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var correctCards = 0;
    $(init);

    function init() {

        // Hide the success message
        $("#next_area_full").hide();

        // Reset the game
        correctCards = 0;
        $('#dragPile').html('');
        $('#dragSlots').html('');

        // Create the pile of shuffled cards
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        var sections = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3];
        var percent = ['Use one measure of soap',
            'Rinse thoroughly (fingers/thumbs/wrists)',
            'Wet hands before applying soap',
            'Use correct amount of product',
            'Ensure thorough wetness',
            'Rub in quickly and vigorously',
            'Use hand cream',
            'Wear gloves for cleaning equipment'];

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            $('<div>' + percent[i] + '</div>').data('number', numbers[i]).attr('section', 'section' + sections[i]).appendTo('#dragPile').draggable({
                containment: '#content',
                stack: '#dragPile div',
                cursor: 'move',
                revert: true
            });
        }

        // Create the drag slots
        var dsections = [1, 2, 3];
        var words = ['Drag here'];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            $('<div>' + words + '</div>').data('number', i).attr('section', 'section' + dsections[i]).appendTo('#dragSlots').droppable({
                accept: '#dragPile div',
                hoverClass: 'hovered',
                drop: handleCardDrop
            });
        }

    }

    function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
        var slotNumber = $(this).attr('section');
        var cardNumber = ui.draggable.attr('section');

        // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
        // change the card colour, position it directly
        // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
        // again

        if (slotNumber == cardNumber) {

             var addTop=$( "div .correct[section='"+slotNumber+"']").length*70;

            ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
            ui.draggable.draggable('disable');

            ui.draggable.position({
                of: $(this),
                my: 'left top+'+addTop,
                at: 'left top'
            });

            ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
            correctCards++;
        }

        // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
        // and reset the cards for another go

        if (correctCards == 5) {
            $("#next_area_full").fadeIn('slow');
        }

    }

})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eDnnB/